# How do I place a form on top of an image and have it resize correctly in CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a custom widget that places the Feedburner subscribe by email form on top of an image (background) in a responsive theme. Right now the image that I am using for the background isn't showing up correctly. There are mainly two problems with the widget right now. One, the image is not resizing correctly within the widget itself. And two, background image is not resizing correctly when the browser is resized.

You can see the custom widget I'm working on if you scroll all the way down to the bottom of the sidebar on [this page](http://noahsdad.com/).

Here is the code that I am using to create the widget.

```
<form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;background: url(http://wpdallas.com/plain/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/noah-side-bar.jpg);" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
    <p>
        <input type="text" style="width:200px;height:20px;" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this stylesheet for the form and will look nice on every display resolution.

```
border: 1px solid #CCC;
padding: 3px;
text-align: center;
background: #f09e30 url(http://wpdallas.com/plain/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/noah-side-bar.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
padding: 35% 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I inserted your code, but the image still isn't sizing correctly. The background image is not resizing correctly. Here is a linke to my page, and you can see the widget (with the code you posted above) at the bottom of the side bar. I'm also using the same image at the very top of the side bar (but without the form) just so you can see what the original image looks like.